# Time Capsule Refuses to Connect After Interrupted File Transfer

Tags: mac, networking, nas, time-capsule

I have a first generation Apple Time Capsule set up as a NAS on my network. I use the built-in hard drive for Time Machine backups, with a 1.5 TB external HDD attached to the Time Capsule over USB.

Whenever I cancel a file transfer from the external drive to my Macbook (or quit a video I had been streaming from it, as was the most recent incident), I can no longer connect to the Time Capsule or the attached drive, and I have to unplug it to get it working again.

How can I fix this? Is it a network error? Could the Time Capsule be at fault or could it be my computer?

Comment: What firmware version is on your Time Capsule?

Comment: 7.4.2 and I'm running 10.6